# How do i send a User object (from Python Flask) back to the frontend (Angular) without sending the password hash and salt?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am using Flask as a Rest API for my WebApp.

In the frontend i use the User object quite often, which is why i need it from the backend to work with the user data.

My concern is, that the user object has an attribute `password`, which is obviously also sent to the frontend, when i make a request for a user object.

Should i define another class like UserPublic to send to the frontend and just strip out the password or is there a better way to do this with Flask, SQLAlchemy, Marshmallow?

I'm not sure if it's even a problem sending the password hash+salt to the frontend. I mean, i don't need it there, so why send it? Password check for login purposes is done in the backend anyway.

This is my User class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    public_id = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname= db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    bday = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False) 
    street = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    zip = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False) #Zip used
    city = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String,  nullable=False, default='Germany')
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    iban = db.Column(db.String)
    bic = db.Column(db.String)
    gender = db.Column(db.CHAR, default='m', nullable=False)

    created_by = db.Column(db.String)
    updated_by = db.Column(db.String)

    membership_status_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('membership_status.membership_status_id'))
    member_since = db.Column(db.Date)
    bookings = db.relationship('Booking', backref="User", lazy='select')
```

Marshmallow Schema:

```
class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        include_fk = True
```

This is the endpoint to get a user object:

```
@app.route('/users/<public_id>', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def get_user(public_id):
    logger.info('Getting user with id: '+str(public_id))
    current_user = User.query.filter_by(public_id=get_jwt_identity()).first()

    if not current_user.admin:
       return jsonify({'message' : 'Not privileged for this action'})

    user = User.query.filter_by(public_id=public_id).first()
    
    if not user:
        return jsonify({'message' : 'No user found with id '+str(public_id)})
    user_schema = UserSchema()
    return user_schema.jsonify(user), 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See doc about [overriding generated fields](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html?highlight=exclude#overriding-generated-fields).

Here's how to exclude the field from the auto-generated schema:

```
class UserSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        include_fk = True
        exclude = ("password", )

    # You may want to only exclude id on dump but keep it on load
    # In this case, add it here by calling `auto_field` yourself
    password = ma.auto_field(load_only=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a little bit of an explanation? What does this actually do?

Comment: Well, auto field defined a field automatically from a field with the same name in the model (https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#generate-marshmallow-schemas). This is what SQLAlchemyAutoSchema uses internally (I guess) but you can call it explicitly.